# Plesk - How to hide port in Nginx forwarding / change listening port?

Tags: nginx, plesk, port-number

I installed the [Docker extension](https://www.plesk.com/extensions/docker/) in my **Plesk Obsidian**.
Then I installed a docker image that raises a web server on localhost:8443. It maps the port 8443 on a chosen target port (let's say 12345).
Then, I used the docker proxy-rule in a domain (my.domain.com) to forward 12345 to 8443 in the docker container.

Everything is working ok, if I go to https://my.domain.com:12345/ I correctly reach the web server in the container.

Now, I'd like to hide the 12345 port in the URL.

Following this: [Hide port in Nginx reverse proxy redirection](https://serverfault.com/questions/627305/hide-port-in-nginx-reverse-proxy-redirection)

I unchecked proxy mode for Nginx and added this addictional directives:

```
listen 443 ssl;
server_name_in_redirect off;
proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:32770;
}
access_log off;
```

But the 12345 is still in the URL... Suggestions?

Comment: Did you forget to put a link here "Following this: Hide port in Nginx reverse proxy redirection" ?

Comment: There are a lot of things that could cause this depending on your specific configurations of Plesk as well as DNS, SSL, and Firewall/port settings. More information is needed. Also, I think this question is more suited for Serverfault.

Comment: @MikeCiffone I added the link, thank you!
I posted here as is a Plesk related issue and as you can read in the link, they suggested to post here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not experienced with the nuances of Plesk, but there are two things stand out to me:

First, if your Docker container's web server is listening on 12345, then `proxy_pass` should be:

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:12345;

# Or if you're serving from a specific path

proxy_pass http://localhost:12345/foo
```

Second, the directive below is passing the hostname and port number to your Docker container.

`proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;`

Unless there is some other reason for this, I would just tell Nginx to forward the host name without the port number.

`proxy_set_header Host $host;`

Then reload nginx.